# How do I add an app in iTunes connect if I use xCode8's automatic signing?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, xcode8

Supposedly xCode8 is "automatically" managing signing. It says, "XCode will create and update profiles, app IDs, and certificates". But if I go in iTunes connect, there are no apps and if I try to add one there is no bundle ID. If I try to register one in the following link, it says the app ID with my identifier is "not available" (because XCode already did it). So, I can't make a new bundle ID because xCode already made one, but I can't use the existing bundle ID because itunes Connect doesn't see it.

Edit: I found a new bundle id that was available to be registered. So before registering I changed the bundle id in xCode. 2 minutes later when I tried to register it gave the same error message of not being available. Inconceivable! Now BOTH of my preferred bundle id's are unavailable...

Edit: I noticed that my team id listed on the website, does not match either of the two team id's I have in my xCode profile, even though both are by the same Apple ID.

Comment: And yes I am signed into the same apple id

Comment: Bundle ID is the name like `com.foobar.myapp` in the `General` tab, so try changing that.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of changing it. How will it fix the issue? Also I don't want to change it because it might mess up some firebase settings which depend on the bundle id.

Comment: It would only give an error like that usually if there's already one existing by the same name.

Comment: Yes, but my id is unique. The one using the existing name, is myself, in xCode8. xCode8 supposedly already handled it "automatically". I don't understand what that means because it still doesn't show up in iTunes Connect so how am I supposed to add the app there?

Comment: Is there another copy of your app associated with the name or a certificate perhaps?

Comment: This is my first time making an app and I've never released previous apps. Also, I used this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839328/itunes-api-lookup-by-bundle-id to look up my bundle id, and it doesn't exist, so it's not because it's already taken

Comment: Okay, I tried what you suggested and changed my bundle ID. It was DEFINITELY available (on the website) before I changed it (in xCode8). Now I try to register, it says it's unavailable!!!!!

Comment: The method you mentioned (in the other question) for checking the Bundle ID will only work if the app is already in the App Store. If the app is not in the App Store and there's already a Bundle ID existing then it will show as not in use even though it really is... It's not an accurate means of determining whether it's available or not.

Comment: That is a good point. However, please see my last comment; I did find an "available" bundle id, and so I changed it in my xCode8 app, and then xCode8 must've done something because when I went back to the website to actually register it, it suddenly became unavailable. Now BOTH bundle id's are unavailable.

Comment: Maybe try the signing manually instead of Automatic. It could have selected the wrong certificates and that's causing it — it can happen. Otherwise maybe contact the support an ask them why it's happening. Without seeing what you are it's tough to definitively say why...

Comment: I noticed that my team id listed on the website, does not match either of the two team id's I have in my xCode profile, even though both are by the same Apple ID.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I'd been using my personal account ("personal team") and only registered for Apple Development Program after I finished developing the app. This is why the first bundle id was not available. Then when I realized a different bundle id was available, I must've messed with Xcode in such a way that my PERSONAL account claimed it first, so it too became unavailable.