# Get App Store link with bundle identifier only

Tags: ios, app-store, bundle-identifier

On Google Play, you can get a link to your app with only the package id.
Eg. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm

Is there a way to do the same for App Store, using only the bundle identifier?
Eg. https://itunes.apple.com/app/gmail-email-by-google/id422689480 works but link is invalid without the `id422689480`: https://itunes.apple.com/app/gmail-email-by-google

Comment: "gmail-email-by-google" is NOT a bundle identifier, it's the name of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search for an app by its **bundle ID**, you should use the iTunes Search API. [Refer to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8839328/3151675)

If you want to create an App Store link from the **name** of the app (as your example states), you have to follow the guidelines [found here:](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1633/_index.html)

> There are three types of App Store Short Links, [...] one for iOS apps [...]:
>
> [...]
>
> `http://appstore.com/<appname>` for example, http://appstore.com/keynote
>
> [...]
>
> To create an App Store Short Link, apply the following rules to your company or app name:
>
> - Remove all whitespace
> - Convert all characters to lower-case
> - Remove all copyright (©), trademark (™) and registered mark (®) symbols
> - Replace ampersands ("&") with "and"
> - Remove most punctuation (See Listing 2 for the set)
> - Replace accented and other "decorated" characters (ü, å,
>     etc.) with their elemental character (u, a, etc.)
> - Leave all other characters as-is.
>
> **Listing 2**
>
> Punctuation characters that must be removed.
>
> ```
> !¡"#$%'()*+,\-./:;<=>¿?@[\]^_`{|}~
> ```

From this, your example will be:

http://appstore.com/gmailemailbygoogle

Comment: http://appstore.com/gmailemailbygoogle has different behavior from https://itunes.apple.com/app/gmail-email-by-google/id422689480 though as it's not accessible from browser. Guess i'll have to stick with the `id422689480`...