# How to get the iOS app Apple ID from a Bundle ID?

Tags: ios, app-store

If I have the Bundle ID of an app, is it possible to programmatically get the Apple ID? eg. the xxx part in this url: http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=xxx

Using the lookup url above, it is possible to do the reverse: get the bundle id given an app's apple id.

I'm ultimately looking to programmatically get the icon of an app, but I only know the Bundle ID of the apps. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iTunes api, lookup by bundle ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839328/itunes-api-lookup-by-bundle-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually remarkably easy and can be done programatically by simply changing the parameter of my original query from 'id' to 'bundleID'

eg. http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=xxx

The response will be a JSON object with the results that will include the thumbnail url among other things. eg.

```
{
  "resultCount":1,
  "results": [
    {
      "screenshotUrls":[...], 
      "ipadScreenshotUrls":[...],
      "artworkUrl512":"...",
      "artistViewUrl":"...", 
      "artworkUrl60":"...",
      "artworkUrl100":"...", 
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```